# Drag UIButton without it shifting to center [Swift 3]

Tags: ios, swift3, drag, uipangesturerecognizer

So I found out how to make a button draggable using the UIPanGestureRecognizer. But the only way I know how to do it is by storing and dragging the button by the center. The problem with this is if you try and drag the button from a corner, the button instantly shifts from the corner to the center. What I'm looking for is a solution that would keep my finger on a selected place while moving without instantly locking onto the center.

The code I'm currently using:

```
func buttonDrag(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Being Dragged")
    if pan.state == .began {
        print("panIF")
        buttonCenter = button.center // store old button center
    }else {
        print("panELSE")
        let location = pan.location(in: view) // get pan location
        button.center = location // set button to where finger is
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done at least in two different ways, one using `GestureRecognizer` **your question way** and other way is subclassing the `UIView` and implementing the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` , `touchesEnded`, `touchesCancelled` in general will work for any UIView subclass can be `UIButton` or `UILabel` or `UIImageView` etc...

In your way, using `GestureRecognizer` I make a few changes you still require a var to keep the origin `CGPoint` of the touch in your `UIButton` so we get the touch position relative to the UIButton and when the drag continue adjust the UIButton origin according to the origin touch position and the positions of the movement

## Method 1 GestureRecognizer

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    var buttonOrigin : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonDrag(pan:)))
        self.button.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    func buttonDrag(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Being Dragged")
        if pan.state == .began {
            print("panIF")
            buttonOrigin = pan.location(in: button)
        }else {
            print("panELSE")
            let location = pan.location(in: view) // get pan location
            button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location.x - buttonOrigin.x, y: location.y - buttonOrigin.y)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

## Method 2 UIView subclass in this case UIButton subclass

Use this `UIButton` subclass

```
import UIKit

class DraggableButton: UIButton {

    var localTouchPosition : CGPoint?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        let touch = touches.first
        self.localTouchPosition = touch?.preciseLocation(in: self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    let touch = touches.first
    guard let location = touch?.location(in: self.superview), let localTouchPosition = self.localTouchPosition else{
        return
    }

    self.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location.x - localTouchPosition.x, y: location.y - localTouchPosition.y)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        self.localTouchPosition = nil
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        self.localTouchPosition = nil
    }

}
```

**Result**

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: Helpful Answer.

Comment: I used this code and it works well. I also want to rotate `UIButton`. can you please help regarding this. Here is Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337323/uibutton-frame-changed-after-move-from-one-position-to-another