# How to move a line created with UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to move a line. I use touchesMoved for it. But my line is shifted relative to the location of the finger with about 100 pixels. Why does it happen?

```
func DrawLine()
{
   let line = CAShapeLayer()
   let linePath = UIBezierPath()
   linePath.move(to: to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
   linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 100, y: 100))
   line.path = linePath.cgPath
   line.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
   line.lineWidth = 1
   line.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
   self.view.layer.addSublayer(line)
}
override func viewDidLoad() 
{        
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DrawLine()
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) 
{
    let touch = touches.first
    guard let location = touch?.location(in: self.view) else
    {
        return
    }
line.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location.x-line.frame.size.width/2, y: location.y-line.frame.size.height/2)
}
```

Comment: You are trying to move a line? is that what you need to do?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392104/drag-uibutton-without-it-shifting-to-center-swift-3/45392805#45392805 maybe can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not starting the line you are drawing from `CGPoint.zero`. Change

```
linePath.move(to: to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 100, y: 100))
```

to

```
linePath.move(to: .zero)
linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
```