# UIButton Frame changed After Move from one Position To Another

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, rotation

I have 1 `UIButton` in `StoryBoard` like below screen and I move `UIButton` from one position to another position by following this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392104/drag-uibutton-without-it-shifting-to-center-swift-3/45392805#45392805).

**Edit**

[image]

Another thing that I want to rotate `UIButton` and for that I have tried below code and it works fine but after rotating `UIButton` when I try to move `UIButton` position from 1 place to another then `UIButton` frame is changed.

Entire `UIButton` code.

```
class DraggableButton: UIButton {

var localTouchPosition : CGPoint?
var lastRotation: CGFloat = 0

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // ROTATION CODE
    let rotate = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(rotatedView(_:)))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(rotate)
}

// SCROLLING CONTENT FROM ONE POSITION TO ANOTHER
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    let touch = touches.first
    self.localTouchPosition = touch?.preciseLocation(in: self)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    let touch = touches.first
    guard let location = touch?.location(in: self.superview), let localTouchPosition = self.localTouchPosition else{
        return
    }

    self.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location.x - localTouchPosition.x, y: location.y - localTouchPosition.y)
    print(self.frame)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    self.localTouchPosition = nil
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    self.localTouchPosition = nil
}

// ROTATION CODE
@objc func rotatedView(_ sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    var originalRotation = CGFloat()
    if sender.state == .began {
        sender.rotation = lastRotation
        originalRotation = sender.rotation
    } else if sender.state == .changed {
        let newRotation = sender.rotation + originalRotation
        sender.view?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: newRotation)
        } else if sender.state == .ended {
            lastRotation = sender.rotation
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

I uploaded issue video.
[image]

**Edit 2**

**If I used `UIButton` Rotation and Movement Code separately then it works but when I write both code it generate this issue.**

Comment: can you post images of your buttons. We would like to see how your button looks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the rotation is about the center of the view, so when you apply the rotation the frame size increases which throws off the distance relative to the origin of the frame.

I was able to fix this by moving the view relative to its center:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    let touch = touches.first
    guard let location = touch?.location(in: self.superview) else { return }

    // Store localTouchPosition relative to center
    self.localTouchPosition = CGPoint(x: location.x - self.center.x, y: location.y - self.center.y)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    let touch = touches.first
    guard let location = touch?.location(in: self.superview), let localTouchPosition = self.localTouchPosition else{
        return
    }

    self.center = CGPoint(x: location.x - localTouchPosition.x, y: location.y - localTouchPosition.y)
    print(self.frame)
}
```

Comment: @Kuldeep thanks for referencing my answer, I was't able to read your question until now, but I found that is answered and solve your issue so I had upvoted the answer as well, Best regards

Comment: Excuse me, I am very new to this part of my project, I copied the codes to my project and now it has this error `Value of type 'MyViewController' has no member 'superview'` can you help in this?

Comment: This code should be added to a `UIView` or a subclass of `UIView` like `UIButton` or `UILabel`.  It appears you added the code to a `ViewController` which isn't correct.  `touchesBegan()` and `touchesMoved()` will be called on a `UIView`.